# UIAutomation on device via command line failing on iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8, instruments, ui-automation

I'm trying to control my app on my device on iOS 8 via the instruments command line tool. The command is failing with the following error:

> Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 8 there is a new option `Enable UI Automation` in the Developer settings on the device:

`Settings -> Developer -> Enable UI Automation`

Switching this to On fixes the issue.